# Prove the inequality, $\root3\of4\sin^2(x/2)<3(\sin x+1-x)^{2/3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

> Prove that $$\left(\sin^2{\frac{x}{2}}\right) \cdot \frac{\sqrt[3]{4}}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{{(\sin x + 1 - x})^{\frac{2}{3}}} <1$$

Comment: You could try minimizing the function $$\frac{(\sin x +1-x)^2}{(1-\cos x)^3}$$, though I think the way to answer it would be nicer.

Comment: @J.Marshall Yes, I've tried to prove this by inserting the maximum and minimum value for sinus function. Thus, I thought that, if sin(x) = 1, then taking the limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{(sinx ....)}}$ when $x \to \infty$,I observed that I get zero. SO I did for sin(x) = 0. I didn't try anything for $\sin^2{x/2}$, because it's maximum and minimum is setted as 0, respectively 1. So, in conclusion, whatever value x takes, the function from left, goes to zero, thus is less than 1.

Comment: This statement is false. For $x = 2$ the LHS is about 1.85 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284%5E%281%2F3%29%29*%28sin+1%29%5E%282%29%2F%283*%28sin+2-1%29%5E%282%2F3%29%29&a=%5E_Real&a=TrigRD_R

Comment: Note that there is a zero of the function $\sin x + 1 - x$ near $x = 1.93$ and $\sin x/2$ does not aproax $0$ for that value, so there is no upper bound of the LHS near said zero.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sin+x+%2B+1+-+x%29%5E%28-2%2F3%29&a=%5E_Real

Comment: @DarthGeek Is it really so ? I tried the same wolphram, also inserted the value 1 and see what I got: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin^2%281%2F2%29*%28%28sin1%29^%28-2%2F3%29%29*%284^%281%2F3%29%29*%281%2F3%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $x \in \left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right]$, then $\frac{1}{2} \leq \sin^2 \frac{x}{2} \leq 1$.

Now consider the function $f(x) = \sin x +1 - x$

For $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$ then $f(x) > 0$ and for $x = \pi$ then $f(x) < 0$ so, since $f$ is continuous, there is a zero of $f$ in $\left(\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right)$. Let $a$ be that zero.

Now let $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{f(x) ^{2/3}}$ Note that $g(x) > 0$ since $g(x) = \left(f(x)^{-1/3}\right)^2$. If $x$ is in a neighbourhood of $a$ then $g(x)$ has no upper bound. Therefore:

$$\left(\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\right)\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}}{3}\frac{1}{(\sin x + 1 - x)^{\frac{2}{3}}} \geq \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}}{3}\cdot g(x)$$

But $g(x)$ has no upper bound so in a small enough neighbourhood of $a$ then

$$\left(\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\right)\frac{\sqrt[3]{4}}{3}\frac{1}{(\sin x + 1 - x)^{\frac{2}{3}}} > 1$$